# Returning from parent function on checking the field values from seperate class

Tags: php, arrays, return

```
<?php
class CustomerLocation{
    public function checkPhone($phone) {
        if(isset($phone) && (strlen($phone) == 10 || strlen($phone) == 12))
        {
            return $phone;
        }
        else
        {
            $aResponse = array(
                "error" => "400",
                "message" => array(
                    "code" => "Invalid_phone",
                    "dev_msg" => "The phone must be at least 10 characters.",
                    "user_msg" => "Please enter valid phone number."
                ),
             );
            return $aResponse;
        }
    }
}

class test {
    public function test()
    {
        $loc = new CustomerLocation();
        $query = array("phone" => $loc->checkPhone('123456'));
        // some more code be executed
    }
}
```

I want to return from the test function with the response message written in `checkPhone` method of `CustomerLocation` class if the phone number does not match the specific condition. But the problem is that I want to check the field of the array which is either by post or request method. How to go about any help will be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: i don't understand your question

Comment: Phone is field in a array whose validation code is written in Customerlocation class. If the phone is invalid then i need to return the response code and exit the function test.

Answer (score 1):

Check this,

```html
<?php
class CustomerLocation{
    public function checkPhone($phone = NULL) {
        if(isset($phone) && (strlen($phone) == 10 || strlen($phone) == 12))
        {
            return $phone;
        }
        else
        {
            $aResponse = array(
                "error" => "400",
                "message" => array(
                    "code" => "Invalid_phone",
                    "dev_msg" => "The phone must be at least 10 characters.",
                    "user_msg" => "Please enter valid phone number."
                ),
             );
            return $aResponse;
        }
    }
}

class test {
    public function testnew($phone1)
    {
        $loc = new CustomerLocation();
        $checkphone =  $loc->checkPhone($phone1);
        $error = isset($checkphone['error']) ? $checkphone['error'] : '';
        if($error == 400){
            $query = array("phone" => $checkphone); 
            return $query;
        }
        else{
            // do some thing
        }
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
$test = new test();
$phone1 = '0123456789';//$_POST['phone'];
$output = $test->testnew($phone1);
print_r($output);
```

May be solve your problem

Comment: Actually there is slight misunderstanding here. The concept is i want to return from the function test if and only if phone doesn't match else i want to continue the code cause below the array there are few more functional things to be done.

Comment: @Amit check above code I have update it will solve your problem.

Comment: Nope this is not exactly what i am looking for.